Is there a way with XSL to include templates on different nested levels of other templates?
Apologies for the confusing initial question, I wasn't sure exactly how to phrase it. I need the  element to appear both inside and outside the other elements.
Please find below my current XSL
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <title></title>
                <link href="flat_bed_9781319350758.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
            </head>
            <body>
            <label for="ex1" id="xvfw87c1517af2de7094cbad80332618">Check text box to hide annotations</label>
            <input id="ex1" type="checkbox"></input>
                <xsl:if test="/sentence/annolabelsentence">
                    <p class="anno-label-sentence">
                        <xsl:apply-templates />
                    </p>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="/sentence/annohandeditsentence">
                    <p class="anno-sentence">
                        <xsl:apply-templates />
                    </p>
                </xsl:if>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="annotated">
        <span class="anno-labelled"><xsl:value-of select="/sentence/annolabelsentence/annotated" /></span>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="annotated">
        <span>
            <span class="anno">
                <span class="anno-begin">Begin <xsl:value-of select="/sentence/annolabelsentence/annotated/@annotation" />. </span>
                <!-- <xsl:apply-templates /> -->
                <span class="anno-labelled"><xsl:value-of select="/sentence/annolabelsentence/annotated" /></span>
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="anno-label"><xsl:value-of select="/sentence/annolabelsentence/annotated/@annotation" /></span>
                <span class="anno-end">End <xsl:value-of select="/sentence/annolabelsentence/annotated/@annotation" />. </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="insert">
        <span class="anno">
            <span class="anno-begin">Begin insert. </span>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
            <span class="anno-insert"><xsl:value-of select="." /></span>
            <span class="anno-end">End insert. </span>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="replace">
        <span class="anno-delete"><xsl:value-of select="." /></span>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="replace">
        <span class="anno">
            <span class="anno-begin">Begin insert. </span>
            <span class="anno-replace"><xsl:value-of select="./@new" /></span>
            <span class="anno-end">End insert. </span> 
            <span class="anno-begin">Begin strikethrough. </span> 
            <!-- <xsl:apply-templates /> -->
            <span class="anno-delete"><xsl:value-of select="." /></span> 
            <span class="anno-end">End strikethrough. </span>
          </span>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="delete">
        <span class="anno">
            <span class="anno-begin">Begin strikethrough. </span>
            <!-- <xsl:apply-templates />-->
             <span class="anno-delete"><xsl:value-of select="." /></span>
            <span class="anno-end">End strikethrough. </span>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="insert-punct">
        <span class="anno">
            <span class="anno-begin">Begin insert. </span>
            <span class="anno-insert-punct"><xsl:value-of select="." /></span>
            <span class="anno-end">End insert. </span>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/sentence/*/*/i|/sentence/*/i">
        <!-- <xsl:for-each select="."> -->
            <i>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </i>
        <!-- </xsl:for-each> -->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>


I would like this XML:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='annotations.xsl'?>
<sentence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="annotation.xsd">
    <annolabelsentence>text
        <annotated annotation='ANNOTATION TEXT'>
        <i>ANNOTATED</i> text </annotated> 
        <i>ITALIC text </i> text
    </annolabelsentence>
</sentence>

To transform into this HTML  (head omitted):
<p class="anno-label-sentence">
text <span class="anno">
<span class="anno-begin">Begin ANNOTATION TEXT. </span>
<span class="anno-labelled">
<i>ANNOTATED</i> text </span>
<span aria-hidden="true" class="anno-label">
ANNOTATION TEXT
</span>
<span class="anno-end">End ANNOTATION TEXT. </span>
</span>
</span> <i>ITALIC text</i> text
</p>

And for this XML:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='annotations.xsl'?>
<sentence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="annotation.xsd">
    <annohandeditsentence>
        text
<replace new="NEW TEXT">text <i>ITALIC TEXT</i> </replace> 
more text <i>italic text</i> more text
    </annohandeditsentence>
</sentence>

To transform into this HTML (head omitted):
<p class="anno-sentence">
text 
<span class="anno">
<span class="anno-begin">Begin insert. </span>
<span class="anno-replace">NEW TEXT</span>
<span class="anno-end">End insert. </span>
<span class="anno-begin">Begin strikethrough. </span>
<span class="anno-delete">text <i>ITALIC TEXT</i> </span>
<span class="anno-end">End strikethrough. </span>
</span> more text <i>italic text</i> more text
</p>

What I've tried previously is commented out. Basically, I expected the final template matching to work.
    <xsl:template match="/sentence/*/*/i|/sentence/*/i">

I also tried apply-templates to most of these but I think that wasn't quite right (because it kept omitting some of the other span elements that are supposed to carry over) even though it got the  elements right.
I also need this to work similarly with <b>, <strong>, and <em>, but I was just starting with one of the inline styles first.

Please pinpoint your question and reduce the example codes to the minimum required to demonstrated the problem you are struggling with - see: [mcve]. My impression is that you do not understand XSLT's processing model. Perhaps reading this can help: https://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/.

I'm sorry, but I'm having great trouble reverse-engineering your requirements from your two examples, and the XSLT code isn't very useful either, because it's wrong. I know it's a little thing, but examples that didn't need scroll-bars might make things clearer.

Having two <xsl:template match="annotated"> doesn't make sense unless you used different modes. And I guess you just want to use templates and apply-templates consistently instead of at some places trying to use xsl:value-of to output stuff.

Hello, I have shortened my examples. Thanks for any help that can be provided.
